# Using regular expressions in Go to Identify a common pattern

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse this string `goats=1\r\nalligators=false\r\ntext=works`.

```
contents := "goats=1\r\nalligators=false\r\ntext=works"


    compile, err := regexp.Compile("([^#\\s=]+)=([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    matchString := compile.FindAllStringSubmatch(contents, -1)
```

my Output looks like `[[goats=1 goats 1] [alligators=false alligators false] [text=works text works]]` 
What I'm I doing wrong in my expression to cause goats=1 to be valid too? I only want [[goats 1]...]

Comment: Why does it do that? Because that's what the docs says it does: "FindStringSubmatch returns a slice of strings holding the text of the leftmost match of the regular expression in s and the matches, if any, of its subexpressions,...". We get both the text and the sub-matches as I understand it.

Comment: If you only want `goats 1` etc, replace all `=` with a space, then split on `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

For another approach, you can use the `strings` package instead:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func parse(s string) map[string]string {
   m := make(map[string]string)
   for _, kv := range strings.Split(s, "\r\n") {
      a := strings.Split(kv, "=")
      m[a[0]] = a[1]
   }
   return m
}

func main() {
   m := parse("goats=1\r\nalligators=false\r\ntext=works")
   fmt.Println(m) // map[alligators:false goats:1 text:works]
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings